# optimize() function does not recognise tol= parameter

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to optimise the first parameter of a function called SSE (which calls other two functions) using the function optimize() but regardless of the parameter tol= (which I set in different ways as a test) gives me always the same results. Here's the code of the function (and sub-functions)

```
SSE <- function(lambda,alpha,y)
{
N <- dim(y)[2]
len <- dim(y)[1]
#########CHECK AGAIN
z <- jglog(y,alpha,lambda)
s <- 0
mean_spec <- apply(z,1,mean,na.rm=T)

s <- sum((z-mean_spec)^2)

cat(lambda,"\t",s,"\n")  #### HERE I WRITE THE VALUES ON THE SCREEN

return(s)
}

glog <- function(y,alpha,lambda)
    z <- log((y-alpha)+sqrt((y-alpha)^2+lambda))

jglog <- function(y,y0,lambda)
{
    z <- glog(y,y0,lambda)
    D <- log(sqrt((y-y0)^2+lambda))

    gmn <- exp(apply(D,2,mean,na.rm=T))
    zj <- z*gmn
    return(zj)
}
```

and this the code in the main which calls the function to optimise

```
lambda <- optimize(SSE,interval=c(low_lim,upper_lim),y0,x,tol=step_threshold)
```

in this case low_lim is  -1143210927 and upper_lim is 5.023143e+24 while step_threshold is 1e-16. But as I mentioned before the output is always the same (even when I set tol=100) and specifically ranges from 3.104473e+24 to 37447978334 with steps which are definitely not equal to tol giving me results for lambda<0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The `tol` parameter just tells `optimize` to stop when the current guess is within that tolerance range.  It may simply be that the first "guess" happens to be exactly correct, rather than slowly converging.

Comment: Further, you don't appear to be feeding sufficient arguments to `optimize` .  Your output `lambda` doesn't exist until `optimize` is completed, so if you're hoping to run a feedback loop, that ain't happening.

Comment: I actually obtain values for lambda during the optimization. What are they referring to then?